# C# - GroupPrincipal.Getmembers(true) not returning domain users, what is the alternative for this?

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

GroupPrincipal.Getmembers(true) returns all users from nested groups but not the domain users (which is the primary group). Is there anyway to fix this, so we can get all users including domain users.

I tried GroupPrincipal.Getmembers(false) but it did not bring in all the users, would be helpful to see the code for this.

I don't want to add domain users as a separate group as it will be hard coding and also the performance takes a hit.

Please give some suggestions on this, been searching for long

Thanks

here is the sample code

```
  using (var context1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ""))
  {
    using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context1,"groupname"))

               {
                  if (group == null)
                 {

                 }
                  else
                  {
                      var users = group.GetMembers(true);
                       foreach (UserPrincipal user in users)
                       {
                          users.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
                         //user variable has the details about the user 
                    }
                 }
                }
            }​
```

Comment: Can you update your code sample so it shows the problem with Domain Users that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @BrianDesmond this is the code which is not pulling domain users if domain users is there in nested group, this is the exact problem I have
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e5b0005-9e0d-4cd6-9982-9a42c03b454f/groupprincipalgetmemberstrue-doesnt-return-users-from-nested-domain-users-group?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended. Domain Users is not populated the same way as normal groups due to some legacy quirks of AD in the Windows 2000 days. Nesting Domain Users in a group really isn't a great idea considering the broad access it implicitly grants. But, if you want to find these members, you'll need to search for users by the `primaryGroupID` attribute. It should be set to 513 for Domain Users.

Comment: Yes that's not good I understand but that's not something I can control, so can you say how to add the primarygroupid? would it be another block of code, or can it be embedded with this. Also since we have lots of users, the performance to takes a hit, would be glad to hear your suggestions, thanks a lot. Also please give an example for the primarygroupid, as I am not aware of it

Comment: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupId=513))` is the LDAP filter for members of Domain Users. I think you're going to need to fall back using direct LDAP queries (e.g. with the `DirectorySearcher` class).

Comment: is there an working example for reference? as I am not sure I get it clearly, where should I add this part in my code?